# Flutter DefaultTabController unexpectedly initializing widget during animation when navigating from tab 0 to tab 2

Tags: dart, flutter, tabs, tabcontrol

I am using a DefaultTabController to manage 3 tabs. The default tab controller is set up like this:

```
DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        initialIndex: 1,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Material(
              type: MaterialType.canvas,
              elevation: 1.0,
              child: Container(
                color: Color(0xFFe3f2fd),
                child: TabBar(tabs: [Tab(text: 'ACTIVITY'), Tab(text: 'LEADERBOARD',) ,Tab(text: 'SETTINGS',)
                  ],
                  labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                  indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      ActivityTab(),
                      LeaderBoardTab(),
                      SettingsTab(rebuildLeaderBoard: refreshLeaderBoard,),
                    ]),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

I am experiencing setState errors when navigating from tab 0 to 2, or 2 to 0. Through testing, I've identified two unexpected behaviors:

1) When navigating from ActivityTab() to SettingsTab() (so from 0 to 2) LeaderboardTab() is being initialized and then disposed. This is causing a setState error.

2) During the same navigation, I'm finding that when leaving a tab, the first thing to occur is that the tab I'm leaving is initialized, causing another setState error.

This odd functionality doesn't occur when only moving 1 tab left or right. It only occurs when moving over two tabs. I found some clues here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13848 but this discussion seems to address a swiping vs. tapping behavior issue that I am not experiencing.

I rebuilt just this segment of the project in a new project and put print statements in the initState and dispose. Here is what gets spit out when moving from tab 0 to tab 2.

```
flutter: INIT TAB ZERO
flutter: DISPOSE TAB ZERO
flutter: INIT TAB TWO
flutter: INIT TAB ONE
flutter: DISPOSE TAB ZERO
flutter: DISPOSE TAB ONE
```

Comment: I discovered one issue: I have an async function that is loading data from Firebase in the Leaderboard Tab. I call setState in this async function. Removing the call to setState in this function eliminates this error. However, I am still having issues with the Streambuilder in ActivityTab being reloaded after I navigate away from that tab.

Comment: Post the full flutter code please.

Comment: I do also have this problem. Even when My Tab1 is only returning a Container(). Could you find a solution for that?

Comment: @M.D. I haven't found a perfect solution, but I have found that checking the mounted property before calling setState has prevented issues of a page rebuilding a widget that is no longer being displayed. It looks like this....

if (mounted) {
setState()
}

Comment: I also faced this issue, specially when using with multiple StreamBuilders. Turned out this was not DefaultTabController but 'TabBarView' was causing the issue. Using IndexedStack instead of TabBarView did the trick for me. Used TabBar's onTap() to change the IndexedStack's index.

Comment: I used FREAKYHUNTER's solution here and had my onTap() change an index value of an InheritedWidget, then I used the value to do my bidding. Very elegant solution FREAKYHUNTER, this is brilliant until Google can fix the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue when using a Webview on the middle tab. In the build method of the middle tab, I used:  if (_tabController.indexIsChanging && _tabController.index != 1) {  return Text("");    } to skip the async webview if we were animating to another tab.